# Encapsulation of modules

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a concrete idea of a structure but I can't identify any pattern to this. So I guess that I do some thing that I should avoid and do in a different way.

My application will control multiple devices (all of the same type) which have multiple communication interfaces and multiple sensors (it's a simplified example to demonstrate the concept!).

Now, below you can find the example code. Now let's only focus on the "Device" class. This is some kind of a man in the middle that doesn't provide any own functionality but only implements other classes.

This sounds for me like a "Facade". But the difference is that a facade implemenets other classes as private instances and provide functions, where in my example instead I declare the implemented instances as public to let the user access them directly.

Achievement:
The (in my real case high) number of services provided by the "Device" get splitted into specific topics (here e.g. "CommunicationServices" and "MeasurementServices"). This should help the user to gain a better orientation over the code.

So, is there an pattern (which I simply can't identify) that represents this implementation below?
Or would that still be called a "Facade"?

```
class Application()
{
    List<IDevice> _listOfDevices = new List<IDevice>;

    readonly Device.Factory _deviceFactory;

    Application(Device.Factory df)
    {
        _deviceFactory = df;
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
        // e.g. instantiate 2 devices
        _listOfDevices.Add(_deviceFactory);
        _listOfDevices.Add(_deviceFactory);
        
        foreach(IDevice device in _listOfDevices)
        {
            int temperature = device.MeasurementServices.TemperatureSensor.ReadTemperature();
            device.CommunicationServices.Wifi.SendMessage(temperature);
        
            //...  and so on
        }
    }
}

public class Device : IDevice
{
    public delegate Device Factory();

    public ICommunicationServices CommunicationServices { get; }
    public IMeasurementServices MeasurementServices { get; }
    
    public Device (ICommunicationServices comServices, IMeasurementServices measurementServices)
    {
        CommunicationServices = comServices;
        MeasurementServices = measurementServices;
    }   
}

public class CommunicationServices : ICommunicationServices
{
    IBluetooth Bluetooth { get; }
    IWifi Wifi { get; }
    ISerial Serial { get; }
    // ... more interfaces

    public CommunicationServices(IBluetooth bt, IWifi wf, ISerial sr)
    {
        Bluetooth = bt;
        Wifi = wf;
        Serial = sr;
    }
}

public class MeasurementServices : IMeasurementServices
{
    ITemperatureSensor TemperatureSensor { get; }
    IHumiditySensor HumiditySensor { get; }
    // ... more sensors
    
    public MeasurementServices (ITemperatureSensor ts, IHumiditySensor hs)
    {
        TemperatureSensor = ts;
        HumiditySensor = hs;
    }
}
```

### **Added after receiving the first input:**

Mark wrote: *"The hierarchy that makes sense to you may not fit the mental model that other people have"*.

Well this is always going to be a problem, thinking about setting up a data structure on a data server that every one is satisfied with is simply impossible.

So the alternative is to define an accessor for each data of the device in the device's interface?
That would be for example:

```
// Interface that is going to have a huge number of accessors...
public interface IDevice
{
    string Device.GetSsid();
    void Device.SetSsid(string ssid);
    int Device.GetLoggerInterval();
    void Device.SetLoggerInterval(int interval_ms);
    // ...
}
```

Talking in a hirarchy

- SSID is part of "CommunicationServices => Wifi => Settings"
- Interval is part of "MeasurementSerivces => Logger => Settings"

The issue which I'm concerned about is just represented in this example: the two data "SSID" and "Interval" are very different topics but would appear aside each other. This doesn't really make it easy to learn the code either.

Or what other approaches are out there to face this issue "train wracking" vs. "single huge interface"? Maybe a mix of both (that would be an inconsequent solution)?

Comment: You can, and should probably, declare the `CommunicationServices` and `MeasurementServices ` properties on the `IDevice` interface, as well as the the `Factory()` delegate. Meaning, the only thing your `Device` class is providing is a constructor, which should probably be done declared in an `abstract` class instead

Comment: uff the delegate should be public as well. Sorry! I'm just correting it.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the properties are public or private, by default  (i.e except if you're explicitly implementing the interface methods like [so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)) the classes which implements an interface must do so publicly

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have a clear vision of the structure of the code, it doesn't have to be a design pattern. Some code is just code, and some common code structures are rather antipatterns (or code smells) than patterns.

[image: Set of 'Code', with subsets of 'Pattern' and 'Antipattern']

I agree that this doesn't look like a Facade. If anything, it looks more like a [Train Wreck](https://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck#:%7E:text=The%20train%20wreck%20anti%20pattern,dealing%20with%20a%20train%20wreck.) - a code smell. Train Wrecks violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). This 'law', however, is controversial:

> "[I'd prefer it to be called the Occasionally Useful Suggestion of Demeter.](https://twitter.com/martinfowler/status/1649793241)"
>
> ― Martin Fowler

Over the years, I've come to increasingly agree with Martin Fowler that this 'law' may not be all that. The OP, however, asks whether the proposed design fits a particular design pattern. I don't think that it does, but I take the liberty to expand the topic slightly to also include various named design principles.

Whether or not you consider the Law of Demeter a proper design principle, I would challenge that the proposed design meets the stated objective:

> This should help the user to gain a better orientation over the code.

I would argue that it does the opposite. The design makes it harder to learn and use the code.

This question is about C# code, and the way that most C# developers interact with an unfamiliar library is via IntelliSense. Given an object `device` of type `Device`, they'd typically start typing a dot (`.`) after `device` to see what options they have. IntelliSense will give them a GUI (an advanced drop-down control) that enumerates the instance members of `Device`. (Phil Trelford [calls this dot-driven development](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/05/25/Designpatternsacrossparadigms)).

So if you type `device.` (notice the trailing dot), you'll be presented with a list of other objects:

- `CommunicationServices`
- `MeasurementServices`
- etc.

When you're 'dotting into' an object, you're typically looking for some *behaviour* - a method to invoke. None of the sub-objects are methods, so you're essentially guaranteed that the first dot *never* produces a useful member.

Users will have to 'dot into' one of the sub-objects to see if the behaviour they're looking for is there. They may, for example, 'dot into' `CommunicationServices` and type another dot to see if the behaviour they're looking for should hang off of it. If it doesn't, they have to delete the `CommunicationServices` property access that the IDE just 'helpfully' created for them, and try the next one.

I've worked with APIs like that, and I understand that they're supposed to be helpful, but they're not - they're exasperating.

You should be wary of introducing hierarchies to help people. There's rarely only one single way to model a given problem domain as a hierarchy, and the hierarchy that makes sense to you may not fit the mental model that other people have.

It'd be more helpful to users to present all members directly on `Device` so that programmers need only 'dot' once.

If you feel that you have too many members on `Device` this might be another code smell, but I can't tell from the OP.

Comment: Well at least I felt in time that some dark programing behaviors are growing inside me that were to be encountered. Thank you very much for your input Mark! After digging into it reading through your inputs and your links I guess you just brought me back on the right tracks!